# Solving simple regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that has lines with the following structure:

```
class.method(params)
```

I want to obtain the class, method and params.
Keep in mind that sometimes there are no params, and there can even be no parenthesis.

So far I've got

```
re.search(r'\w+', string)
```

But if params are enclosed in quotation marks, they are removed, and I want to keep them.

How do I keep them?

Examples:

```
>>> process('class.method(params)')
('class','method','params')
>>> process('class.method("params")')
('class','method','"params"')
>>> process('class.method('params')')
('class','method',''params'')
>>> process('class.method()')
('class','method','')
>>> process('class.method')
('class','method','')
```

Comment: You need to provide way more input and expected output otherwise you might as well use `.+`.

Comment: Is the file you're attempting to parse (note the word parse there) actually a language source file?

Comment: @smerny I realized I wanted them in groups

Comment: @HamZa I've added some examples

Comment: @JonClements It's a custom syntax I'm creating.

Comment: @Erandros It's a custom syntax you're creating? Err, you should be able to tell us what the rules are to identify it and parse it correctly then shouldn't you? :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
>>> import re
>>> reg_exp = '(\w+)\.(\w+)\(?([^)]*)\)?'
>>> re.match(reg_exp, 'class.method("params")').groups()
('class', 'method', '"params"')
>>> re.match(reg_exp, "class.method('params')").groups()
('class', 'method', "'params'")
>>> re.match(reg_exp, "class.method()").groups()
('class', 'method', '')
>>> re.match(reg_exp, 'class.method(params)').groups()
('class', 'method', 'params')
>>> re.match(reg_exp, 'class.method').groups()
('class', 'method', '')
```

- `(\w+)` is a capturing group that matches 1 or more alphanumeric characters
- `([^)]*)` is a capturing group that matches any character except `)`
- `\(?` matches `(` or nothing
- `\)?` matches `)` or nothing

`\(?([^)]*)\)?` helps to handle situations with no params and parenthesis provided.

Comment: OP didn't mention wanting groups, the problem seems to be that the `\w` wasn't matching quotes.

Comment: Also I would put the parens/params all in a single group because for example if there is no `(` there should be no `)`. Something like `(\([^)]*\))?`

Comment: Exactly, it doesn't work if params is enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: @Erandros ok, I've replace `\w*` with `.*` - will work with quotation marks.

Comment: @alecxe Why don't you use non-greedy matching `.*?` ?

Comment: Thanks! I learned how to use ^, +, ?, *, and what parenthesis meant. It's funny that the most effective (if not only) way of learning regex is doing regex. Feels like sports...

Comment: @Erandros great, that it works for you. So many criticism from other so members though :)

Comment: @alecxe as a 10K user you should show example and ask what the OP really wants in the comment section but instead you rushed to post an answer which resulted into 100 edits.

Comment: @HamZa yeah, it's definitely a reasonable criticism. Really appreciate that. I agree that I rushed to post an answer - well, we are all here to learn, I still need to a lot learn more to help people better. I just chose this way - try to share what I know and can solve. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I didn't feel they tried to deny your efforts, they were very respectful.
Excluding that last dogmatic/demanding "you are 10k you should do X" or that exaggerated "100 edits". Having that exception, I felt they were respectful.